# How to edit the following php check on my script?

Tags: php

**Quick explanation**

I've got an option on my website for the users to change their class on their character.
As you can see below on my script... the main check is if 4 days elapsed since the last class change otherwise an error message will appear.

**What am I trying to do?**

I will add another column `SpecialPoints` on `USERDATA` table and I want to do the following: *IF 0 Special Points ---> Check if 4 days elapsed and If not throw the error message -- CC_RECENT_TRANSFER. Otherwise IF more than 0 Special Points, ignore the date check requirement and directly continue to execute the script below to complete the class change..*

Any clue how I can add that on my script below? I've tried multiple times few ways to include check for that but I am somehow missing the real point. Just an example of how I can do that will help me out a lot.

**My current option which mainly checks only for TransferTime:**

```
    $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, TransferTime FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = ? AND (TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-4,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL) and zone<253 and authority<>255', $character);
     if ($num_rows == -1)
     {
      $db->GetError(__file__, __line__);
      $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('DB_ERROR');
      return false;
      }
     else if ($num_rows == 0)
      {
      $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('CC_RECENT_TRANSFER');
      return false;
      }
...........
```

P.S. I use MSSQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your SQL query to include the new requirements:

```
$db->doQuery('SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, TransferTime 
    FROM USERDATA 
    WHERE strUserId = ? AND 
    (SpecialPoints > 0 OR (SpecialPoints = 0 AND (TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-4,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL)))
    AND zone<253 AND authority<>255', $character);
```

The parentheses have grouped your new conditions - either SpecialPoints is greater than 0, or SpecialPoints is 0 and the TransferTime is checked the same as before.

Comment: That means if `SpecialPoints > 0`, it will ignore the rest of `OR (SpecialPoints = 0 AND (TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-4,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL))` ..?

Comment: Right.  The way the parentheses are setup, it's simply like `A OR B`.  So if A is true it does not need to look at B.

Comment: Awesome. I actually succeed to create my own check but it was way complex than this one. I've edited the query and removed any transfertime checks and moved them into separate function ... yours is the best one. Thank you a lot. Answer fully accepted. GOD BLESS YOU!